# I have this SQL Procedure... Can somebody explain how to use it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is the procedure..

```
create Procedure LoadTable
@TableName varchar(150)
as
begin
Declare @BCPCMD varchar(8000)
declare @BCPPath varchar(150)
select @BCPPath = 'C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server\100\tools\binn\'
select @BCPCMD = '"'+@BCPPath+'BCP" TheDW.DBO.' + @TableName + ' in C:\'+ @TableName +         '.BCP -w -T'
exec master..XP_CmdShell @BCPCMD
end
go
Execute LoadTable "Tables_Table"
Go
Execute LoadTable " Extract_File_Translation_Table"
Go
```

I am really new at Sql stuff so any help will be appreciated

Comment: The example of use is included (twice) after `go`.

Comment: it is loading a sql script correct?
if so where do I put the location?

Comment: What is your intent?  If you're just trying to learn tsql - then this isn't the way.  If you're trying to use this sproc to acheive a known goal, you might have more luck asking about the goal.  The way your post is now, it's like you've given the answer and want SO to come up with the question.

Comment: My intent is to load a sql script ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up SSMS.

type

```
go
Execute LoadTable "Tables_Table"
Go
Execute LoadTable " Extract_File_Translation_Table"
Go
```

Hit F5

[More on using SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177264.aspx).

That space looks suspicious in  `LoadTable " Extract_File_Translation_Table"`

Comment: the system could not find the path specified

Comment: where do I put the sql script

Comment: You will need to alter the proc to use the path to the bin folder *on the server* this: C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server\100\tools\binn\ won't necessarily be the same on all servers.

Comment: can I do a .sql or does it have to be .bcp

Comment: In a suitable database. The script is a stored procedure, I suppose if you are loading a table in foo, you'd execute "Use Foo", then create the stored procedure, then execute it.

Comment: Bcp doesn't care what file extension you use.

Comment: I'm inferring you already have the stored proc created. Are you asking where to put the file to be imported? It looks like it will go on the root of the C:\ drive *on the server*

Comment: alright I tried Execute LoadTable "Tables_Table" .. after putting Tables_Table.sql in the C:/ ... I still get a "The system can't find the path specified"

Comment: where did you get that script? Another suspicious thing is that the space in missing from "C:\ProgramFiles\..." Have to tracked down the true location of bcp.exe?

Comment: i put the script in C:/ and the BCP.exe is in the place specified C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server\100\tools\binn

Comment: When you execute the proc does print out the statement is is getting ready to execute. You can take that command and execute it on the command line where you can fiddle with it until the spaces and quotes are correct.  These sort of scripts usually have errors with spaces and quotes since one is writing a command line inside of a string.

Comment: when I ran the script it said it executed correctly

Comment: Then check to see if there is data in your target table and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Books Online for the BCP command; this stored procedure is an attempt to rapidly load data from a flat file.  I should note that this proc it relies on the XP_CmdShell procedure, which can be exploited as a vulnerability.  Use with caution.